# APPNAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj --> Wrong APPNAME

Tags: ios

We renamed our App according to the guidelines on how to do that.
Locally it works just fine but when pushed/pulled to Git to another machine the .xcworkspace doesn't open because it searches for OLDNAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj instead of NEWNAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?
There is no mention of the OLDNAME in the project anymore what so ever.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the DeliveryData on another machine?

Comment: I resolved it now by just going into all the files inside the .xcodeproj folder and there were still some mentions of the old name.
Deleted the files or changed the name to the new one.